# Jenkins shared library - how to define common options for a declarative pipeline

Tags: jenkins, groovy, closures, jenkins-pipeline, jenkins-declarative-pipeline

I have many similar configs in declarative pipelines, like agent, tools, options, or post section. Is there any option to define those option somehow, so that an individual job has only to define the steps (which may come from a shared library)?

There is a [description at "Defining a more stuctured DSL"](https://jenkins.io/doc/book/pipeline/shared-libraries/#defining-a-more-structured-dsl), where there is something similar to that what I want to achieve, but this seems to apply to scripted pipelines.

```
pipeline {
    agent {
        label 'somelabel'
    }
    tools {
        jdk 'somejdk'
        maven 'somemaven'
    }
    options {
        timeout(time: 2, unit: 'HOURS')
    }

    stages {

         stage('do something') {
            steps {
                    doSomething()
            }
         }            

    }
    post {
        failure {
            emailext body: '${DEFAULT_CONTENT}', subject: '${DEFAULT_SUBJECT}',
                    to: 'some@mail.com', recipientProviders: [[$class: 'CulpritsRecipientProvider'], [$class: 'RequesterRecipientProvider'], [$class: 'DevelopersRecipientProvider']]
        }
    }
}
```

Actually, I tried something like [that](https://jenkins.io/doc/book/pipeline/shared-libraries/#defining-declarative-pipelines), trying to pass a closure to the pipeline, but this does not seem to work. Probably if it worked, there was some documentation on how to do it.

```
def call(stageClosure) {
    pipeline {
        agent {
            label 'somelabel'
        }
        tools {
            jdk 'somejdk'
            maven 'somemaven'
        }
        options {
            timeout(time: 2, unit: 'HOURS')
        }

        stages {

             stageClosure()           

        }
        post {
            failure {
                emailext body: '${DEFAULT_CONTENT}', subject: '${DEFAULT_SUBJECT}',
                        to: 'some@mail.com', recipientProviders: [[$class: 'CulpritsRecipientProvider'], [$class: 'RequesterRecipientProvider'], [$class: 'DevelopersRecipientProvider']]
            }
        }
    }
}
```

and calling it somehow like this:

```
library 'my-library@master'

callJob{

     stage('do something') {
          steps {
                doSomething()
                }
          }  
  }
```

Comment: I don't think shared libraries work well with declarative pipelines right now. Shared libraries can declare the entire pipeline or none of it.

Comment: there are several difficulties to make a shared lib with a declarative pipeline so we must wait to have some solutions from community

Answer (score 3):

I created a full flow

```
//SbtFlowDockerLarge.groovy
def call(int buildTimeout,String sbtVersion,List<String> fbGoals, List<String> masterGoals ){

    def fbSbtGoals = fbGoals.join ' '
    def masterSbtGoals = masterGoals.join ' '

    pipeline {
        agent { label DPgetLabelDockerLarge() }
        options {
            timestamps()
            timeout(time: buildTimeout, unit: 'MINUTES')
            disableConcurrentBuilds()
            buildDiscarder(logRotator(daysToKeepStr: '35'))
        }

        stages {
            stage('Prepare') {
                steps {
                    setGitHubBuildStatus("Running Build", "PENDING")
                    echo "featureTask :  ${fbSbtGoals}"
                    echo "masterTask :  ${masterSbtGoals}"
                }
            }
            stage('Build') {
                when {
                    not { branch 'master' }
                }
                steps {
                    sbtTask tasks: "${fbSbtGoals}", sbtVersion: sbtVersion
                }
            }
            stage('Deploy') {
                when {
                    branch 'master'
                }
                environment {
                    TARGET_ENVIRONMENT='prod'
                }
                steps {
                    sbtTask tasks: "${masterSbtGoals}", sbtVersion: sbtVersion
                }
            }
        }
        post {
            success {
                setGitHubBuildStatus("Build complete", "SUCCESS")
            }
            failure {
                setGitHubBuildStatus("Build complete", "FAILED")
            }
            always {
                junit allowEmptyResults: true, testResults: '**/target/test-reports/*.xml'
                dockerCleanup()
            }
        }
    }
}
```

and here is the Jenkinsfile

```
@Library('aol-on-jenkins-lib') _
def buildTimeout = 60
def sbtVersion = 'sbt-0.13.11'
OathSbtFlowDockerLarge (buildTimeout, sbtVersion,['clean test-all'],['clean test-all publish'])
```

Comment: what's this `DPgetLabelDockerLarge`

Comment: @RajeshRajendran it’s an internal function that return the slave type

Comment: Thank you for the info. But internal function means, jenkins internal or your's? and one more thing, I have a branch which contains all shared library, and I need to checkout scm for private repo, wher the jenkinsfile is. I am using labels for multiple jenkins slave containers. If I do checkout scm in jenkinsfile, i'll get the code but can't be sure that it'll be in the same node, where the shared lib pipeline runs. can you suggest any solution?

Comment: @RajeshRajendran my function

Comment: What are you trying to do ?

Comment: @mojor The reason which I don't want to use git : url, branch, and credentialsID is in my shared lib, I'll have to always pass the credentialsID, but `checkout scm` will do that for free.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/184511/discussion-between-rajesh-rajendran-and-mor-lajb).